# Trying to commit changes subversive

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I am trying to commit changes that I have made om a project but get the following message.

Some of the selected resources are conflicting. You should resolve the conflicts before commiting.

Any advice perhaps as to how to resolve this so that I can commit?

Kind regards

Comment: At first you should do an update. After this eclipse will mark you conflicting files and you can begin to merge them to resolve the conflicts. Then you should be able to commit.

Comment: Where do you have conflicts? On files or on folders?

Comment: In a file. How will I see the conflictinf file and how can I resolve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the project and select `Team` -> `Synchronize with Repository`. Switch to the `Team Synchronization` perspective. The left view `Synchronize` shows your local and the remote changes. You can set the filter to conflicting resources by selecting the red icon (with a arrow to the left and right) from the toolbar. Double click one resource and you will see the conflicts. After you resolved them you can commit your changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is getting occurred as other guys in your project has already done some changes on the same line of code that you are working upon and committed (checked in) the file.

Since you do not have their changes with you, message is coming.

Its a good practice to always take an update before committing anything.

Since you are getting message and now if you will try to update the files then you will either get conflict (if your code changes are colliding with the other guy's changes) or probably the file will get merged (if on the same file the other guy has done changes on some other lines of code which you were not working upon).

After updating the conflicted files will be shown in red color in the svn console. You can right click on that red color file and "Edit Conflicts" manually. Once done your file is ready for committing.

Hope this helps.